# Script Editor Web Part works but main page does not fires script sections

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

Like many question I have seen the jQuery document.ready works in the web-part during editing but not after I save the page.
I found this [code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156984/script-editor-web-part-not-recognizing-jquery) on SO and thought I run a couple of test to see what was happening, I added a couple of alert boxes to see how jQuery was being loaded. to my surprise the script section is never called? below is how I have my setup any help would be great. I'm using SharePoint 365 2013

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../master_page_items/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../master_page_items/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../master_page_items/picture_slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>


<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

// Only do anything if jQuery isn't defined
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {

if (typeof $ == 'function') {
    // warning, global var
    thisPageUsingOtherJSLibrary = true;

  alert('thisPageUsingOtherJSLibrary NOT DEFINE');
}

function getScript(url, success) {

    var script     = document.createElement('script');
         script.src = url;

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    done = false;

    // Attach handlers for all browsers
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {

        done = true;

            // callback function provided as param
            success();

            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
            head.removeChild(script);

        };

    };

    head.appendChild(script);

};

getScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js', function() {

    if (typeof jQuery=='undefined') {

        // Super failsafe - still somehow failed...
       alert('Super failsafe - still somehow failed...');

    } else {

        // jQuery loaded! Make sure to use .noConflict just in case
        fancyCode();

        if (thisPageUsingOtherJSLibrary) {

           alert('thisPageUsingOtherJSLibrary');

        } else {

            // Use .noConflict(), then run your jQuery Code
            alert('Use .noConflict(), then run your jQuery Code');
        }

    }

});

} else { // jQuery was already loaded

// Run your jQuery Code
   alert('Run your jQuery Code');

};



</script>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: no I don't  very strange

Comment: can you put this script in a file and do a line by line debug in browser?

Comment: here is what I did, I figured out that the jQuery document ready function is already called before my page is loaded so I removed the JQuery(document).ready function and just place my code within the script tag and it worked for now. I say this because this happen before  and then it stop working. This is very strange behavior.